# Isn't this question (about Jews not having to follow the law) too broad?

Tags: discussion

[How is teaching that Jews don't have to follow the Law reconciled with the Word of God and Jesus?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/36286/how-is-teaching-that-jews-dont-have-to-follow-the-law-reconciled-with-the-word)

This is four separate questions:

> 1. What are some of the official explanations for why it's OK for Jews not to follow the law today? For example eat bread on passover, or
>      work on Yom Kippur? How are the above verses addressed?
> 2. How did Christians officially address these words of Jesus throughout history, when they taught that Jews shouldn't follow some
>      or all of the Law of Moses (for example the ceremonial laws)? What do
>      they think it means to be called least in the kingdom of Heaven?
> 3. Jesus told a man how to get eternal life. If Christians do not consider following the commandments essential to salvation, why did
>      Jesus say what he said?
> 4. Why would they ask Paul to dispel these rumors and in fact affirm that Paul himself is living in obedience to the law?

I commented, "Definitely split it into four questions, and specify what tradition you want to hear from. Different denominations *will* answer these questions differently." Then I flagged it as too broad. It's been over a month. (Edit: No it hasn't. I made a mistake looking at my flagging history when I wrote that.) The flag was deemed helpful, but the question remains open.

I actually think questions 2 and 3 could be combined into one question. Question 1 *may* be a duplicate of [To what extent does the Law of Moses still apply?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/456/to-what-extent-does-the-law-of-moses-still-apply) but I'm not sure (I'm looking at the top-voted non-accepted answer, which is a great overview but not very thorough). But I do think each of the three (or four) questions would need to specify a tradition.

As it is, the mega-question, with all three/four questions together, seems way too broad. I would love to provide an answer to each of the questions, but with them combined, it just doesn't seem practical.

Comment: IMO, it's too broad on several counts. 1) as you point out, it asks multiple questions. 2) it also asks for multiple perspectives. I already VtCed, but my vote has expired.

Comment: My vote has also expired. Perhaps flag it and a mod will agree.

Comment: Okay, flagged it.

Comment: My vote expired too. How did this happen?

Comment: @curiousdannii Well, that's only three, but perhaps we voted at different times. Seems to have happened with the other question you've meta posted about (the one on Matthias or Paul being the 12th apostle).

Comment: I wonder if close vote history of a question can be queried from the api. I'd like to see *exactly what* happened. Actually, what would be nice is if 3K+ rep users could see a close and reopen vote history, just like the revision history. It seems like all the review actions are lumped into their respective user pages, but that is not very useful unless you want to review that user's actions. Maybe I should see what's on MSE about this.

Comment: @fredsbend I did imagine it must've been something like that.  Still we're usually all fast voters, so it's a bit surprising.

Comment: Here's the review: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/review/close/22948

Comment: **6** close votes! Incredible that it didn't get closed. The first ones must have expired just before the last ones were made.